# Why does my Python daemon stops after a while?

Tags: python, linux, daemon

I'm doing a small factored server room monitoring system with the raspberry pi. The python daemon that checks if the temperature and humidity is in green range stops after a few hours/ days. It loads in a while loop every 2 seconds a config file where the temperature and humidity intervals are defined and then it checks if the current values are in range.
Here is the code of the python daemon (checkSensorData.py):

```
import time

from tools import Tools
from sensorData import SensorData
from monlog import MonLog
from daemon import runner

CONF_FILE = "/home/pi/sys-conf/sys.conf"
DELAY = 2

class CheckSensorData():

    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = "/dev/null"
        self.stdout_path = "/dev/null"
        self.stderr_path = "/dev/null"
        self.pidfile_path = "/tmp/checkSensorData.pid"
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5
        self.temp_status = -1 # temperature status (0 => to low, 1 -> ok, 2 -> to high)
        self.humd_status = -1 # humidity status (0 => to low, 1 -> ok, 2 -> to high)

    def run(self):
        self.monlog = MonLog()
        self.sd = SensorData()
        while True:
            time.sleep(DELAY)
            conf = Tools.loadConf(CONF_FILE)
            self.check(conf)

    def check(self, conf):
        temperature = self.sd.getTemperature()
        humidity = self.sd.getHumidity(temperature)
        if temperature > float(conf["max_temperature"]) and self.temp_status!=2:
            self.monlog.warning("Temperature is too high: "+str(temperature)+" °C")
            self.temp_status = 2
        elif temperature < float(conf["min_temperature"]) and self.temp_status!=0:
            self.monlog.warning("Temperature is too low: "+str(temperature)+" °C")
            self.temp_status = 0
        elif temperature >= float(conf["min_temperature"]) and temperature <= float(conf["max_temperature"]) and self.temp_status!=1:
            self.monlog.info("Temperature is ok: "+str(temperature)+" °C")
            self.temp_status = 1
        if humidity > float(conf["max_humidity"]) and self.humd_status!=2:
            self.monlog.warning("Relative humidity is too high: "+str(humidity)+" %")
            self.humd_status = 2
        elif humidity < float(conf["min_humidity"]) and self.humd_status!=0:
            self.monlog.warning("Relative humidity is too low: "+str(humidity)+" %")
            self.humd_status = 0
        elif humidity >= float(conf["min_humidity"]) and humidity <= float(conf["max_humidity"]) and self.humd_status!=1:
            self.monlog.info("Relative humidity is ok: "+str(humidity)+" %")
            self.humd_status = 1

checkSensorData = CheckSensorData()
daemonRunner = runner.DaemonRunner(checkSensorData)
daemonRunner.do_action()
```

And here are the two methods from the Tools class to load the config file:

```
@staticmethod
def getLines(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        return file.readlines()

@staticmethod
def loadConf(confFile):
    lines = Tools.getLines(confFile)
    conf = {}
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        line = lines[i].strip(" \n")
        if line!="" and line[0]!="#":
            data = line.split(":")
            conf[data[0]] = data[1]   # conf[key] = value
    return conf
```

Does anyone have an idea why the daemon stops after a few hours/ days?

Comment: How are you running the daemon?  On a side note, it's likely to take a few minutes for the temperature and/or humidity to change in the room so checking every 2 seconds might be a little too often. ;)

Comment: I'm running the daemon as root with start/ stop (# ./checkSensorData.py start). The sensors respond within a second. I've also tested it with a delay of 5 seconds, but same issue.

Comment: There are 100 reason why it could be failing, but you're piping stderr and stdout to /dev/null so you'll never know.  Pipe these to a file and take a look at them next time you've noticed it's stopped.

Comment: Ok, that is a good idea, I will change it ;-)

Comment: `with open(filename, 'r') as f: return f.readlines()` avoids skipping the `close()` in case of exceptions and is the idiomatic way. Also, what strikes me is that you repeatedly read the configfile every two seconds, intentionally? Lastly, check the CPU and memory use (using e.g. htop), maybe you have a resource leak.

Comment: I have change open(filename, 'r') to with open(filename, 'r')... My script uses 1.4% of memory and 0.0% of CPU.

Comment: This indicates that it's probably not running out of control. It's hard to tell what's going on. I'd try to remove either the daemon part or the sensor access and see if it still hangs.